# Populate fields with default values using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to use jquery to populate fields with default values. For example, say I have a field for email address and I want to add example@email.com in grey italic text in the box and the remove it once the user clicks on the field. Is there any good way to do this with a plugin or something? I would really like to avoid toggling an absolutely positioned div if possible.

Comment: doesn't anyone program in JAVASCRIPT anymore? Why do so many people assume jQuery is a programming language?

Comment: @SpliFF it was TAG as JQUERY... no tags for javascript... see?

Comment: so WHY is it tagged jQuery then?

Comment: @SpliFF, jQuery IS Javascript, just tested and packaged so I don't have to do those two things, saving me time. AND it works the way I would want it to, doing the things I always did, but easier for me with a community of contributers such as plug-ins. It is tagged that way by the person who asked the question, specifically askign about a plug-in.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed everyone knew Jquery was js.

Comment: @Mark you're saying Javascript is NOT tested and packaged? Anyway, this wouldn't be the first SO question I've seen where the question tries to define a solution instead of the problem. Using jQuery just for the sake of it is simply not a reasonable choice when the underlying language provides the required functionality in a one-liner like you see in my answer below. On top of that HTML5 provides the functionality as an attribute so defining the scope of the solution as "jquery" simply narrows answers down to the worst solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mFGy8/2/)

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
<input type="text" id="name" />
```

then,

```
$(function(){
   $('#email').focus(focus).blur(blur)[0].defaultValue="example@email.com";
   $('#name').focus(focus).blur(blur)[0].defaultValue="Type name here";
})

function focus(){
   this.value = (this.value == this.defaultValue)?'':this.value;
}
function blur(){
   this.value = (this.value == '')?this.defaultValue:this.value;
}
```

---

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mFGy8/3/) with styles

```
$(function(){
    $('#email, #name').addClass('default');
    $('#email').focus(focus).blur(blur)[0].defaultValue="example@email.com";
    $('#name').focus(focus).blur(blur)[0].defaultValue="Type name here";
});

function focus(){
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
        $(this).removeClass('default');
    }
}
function blur(){
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
        $(this).addClass('default');
    }
}​
```

Comment: How would I add styles to the default values only?

Answer (score 4):

**Updated:** This new version makes the same code reusable for multiple `<input>` elements

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/XTKu8/

HTML

```
<input id='name' class='italic' value='some name' type='text' />
<input id='email' class='italic' value='example@email.com' type='text' />
```

jQuery

```
$('.italic').each(function() { $(this).data('defaultValue',$(this).val()); })
    .focus(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if($th.val() == $th.data('defaultValue'))
            $th.toggleClass('italic').val('');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if($th.val() == '')
          $th.toggleClass('italic').val($th.data('defaultValue'));
    });​
```

---

**Original**

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRLK2/

HTML

```
<input id='email' type='text' />​
```

jQuery

```
$('#email').focus(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    if($th.val() == 'example@email.com') {
        $th.val('')
            .css({'color':'#000','font-style':'normal'});
    }
})
    .blur(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        if($th.val() == '') {
            $th.val('example@email.com')
            .css({'color':'#888','font-style':'italic'});
        }
    })
    .val('example@email.com')
    .css({'color':'#888','font-style':'italic'});​
```

**EDIT:** I forgot about the italic part, and should have used focus. Updated.

Also, instead of setting specific CSS styles, you may want to place those styles in a class and use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`, or just `.toggleClass()`.

- http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

As **karim79** noted, it is better to add classes instead of styles. You could do this instead:

```
.italic {
    color:#888;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

Then

```
$th.val('')
    .removeClass('italic');

$th.val('example@email.com')
    .addClass('italic');
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution. I can think of one tiny little improvement though - which would be to use `addClass('italic')` and `removeClass('italic')` instead of those chunky `.css` calls (and of course, putting the style into a class named 'italic' or such).

Comment: @karim79 - Thanks :o) and I agree. I added that note at the end of the answer, but probably a good idea to make it explicit. I'll update.

Comment: this is good for one input field only... and would make much effort to copy paste almost the same code for other fields... please take a look at my answer... :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344465/populate-fields-with-default-values-using-jquery/3344570#3344570

Comment: @Reigel - Just needs a little refactoring to make it reusable. http://jsfiddle.net/beU5t/

Answer (score 1):

```
<input onfocus="this.select()" type="text" value="example@email.com" />
```

This highlights the text upon clicking in the text box. It means when you click it again after typing in it before, the text won't vanish again.

If you really do want the text to just vanish upon click everytime, use this.

```
<input onfocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="example@email.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$( "#emailField")
   .val( "example@email.com")
   .bind( "focus", function(){
        $(this).val("");
   })
   .bind( "onblur", function {
        $(this).val("example@email.com");
   });
```

Comment: That's good but you'd probably only want to set the value back to the sample value when the user hasn't typed stuff into it!

Comment: Dont you think we need a check on blur, for not replace the text written by user. Your code will replace any text entered by user.

Comment: @Pointy, @harshh you both correct. Wrote my answer out of head just a sketch for final solution, I agree need to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is exactly what this offers: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

```
 /// Adds the watermark to the text entry areas
var watermarkText = 'example@email.com ';
$(function()
{
    $('.myEmailArea').watermark(watermarkText)
});
```

EDIT: show some CSS for this example:

```
.watermark
{
    color: #808080 !important;
}
```

Comment: FYI, this also puts the watermark back after you blank the field, allows special styles such as italic etc. based on CSS, good plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
input.defaulted_input {
    color: #999999;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

And this Javascript:

```
var email_input = $("#email");
var email_value = email_input.val();
email_input.bind("focus blur", function() {
            if (this.value === email_value) {
                this.value = "";
                email_input.toggleClass("defaulted_input");
            } else if (this.value === "") {
                this.value = email_value;
                email_input.toggleClass("defaulted_input");
            }

        });​
```

SEE: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/KE43P/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for something so trivial, it's excessive.

```
<input type="text" value="initial value" onfocus="if (this.value=='initial value') this.value=''">
```

Comment: True, but if you already have jQuery on the page, why not use it?

Comment: because 99% of the time you're just adding extra overhead for no gain. In this case by asking the browser to search through the DOM when the object you want is already pointed to by 'this'.